# Workflow adds # to email addresses

Tags: designer-workflow, email

I created a workflow in SharePoint Designer for a calendar that pauses until a calculated field (starttime-14) equals today, then emails people listed as Attendees and Created By.  It emails the Created By person just fine, but adds a # before the name of Attendees which is causing the email to fail.
I attempted to create my own attendee column and renamed it "invitee" and "people", but it is doing this with any people/group type column. 
Has anyone had this problem before?  Or has any advice on how to address this?
Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 2):

Does your "Attendees" column allow for multiple people entries? I'm guessing "yes".

If so, the workflow may be having difficulties parsing the list of people. Hence, the "#" preceding names.

Try toggling the column to not allow multiple entries and verify that works.

Also, in your SPD workflow, ensure the "Return field as" is either "Login Name" or "Login Names, Semicolon Delimited" (not "As String").